# añadir imagen jpg con jspdf

Tags: javascript

Estoy creando un PDF con jspdf y va todo correcto hasta que intento insertar una imagen.

He visto este código por internet pero me da que no es correcto:

```
var logo = new Image();

logo.src = 'imagen.jpg';

doc.addImage(logo, 'JPEG', 10, 10, 50, 70);
```

Metí la librería `jspdf.plugin.addimage.js` también pero no funciona

Comment: ¿Cual es el error que te aparece?

Comment: no me aparece ninguno, simplemente no imprime el pdf

Comment: Convierte la imagen a base64 primero y luego la añades al documento.

Comment: mediante canvas en javascript o con paginas externas?. Perdona la pregunta pero soy nuevo en programacion y no se lo que es ni para que vale

Comment: Ya he conseguido poner la imagen pero sale en blanco y negro y con muy mala calidad. Alguna manera para que salga lo mas parecido a la imagen real?

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con algo así

En js

```
var doc = new jsPDF('p','mm','letter');

var logo = new Image();
logo.src = 'foto.jpg';
doc.addImage(logo, 'JPEG', 15, 40,148,210);
doc.save('Prueba.pdf');
```

En html

```
<div id="content">
    <img src="imagen.jpg" alt="foto">       
</div>
<div id="editor"></div>

<button id="cmd">Generar pdf</button>
```